# Is there a (relatively simple) function bounding the two Fresnel integrals?

Tags: calculus, upper-lower-bounds, fresnel-integrals

I just discovered the two [Fresnel integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) and it really seems like they are bounded by two functions (maybe exponentials?). Here is an image explaining what I mean:

[image: A graph plotting the two Fresnel integrals with an upper and a lower bounding function drawn by hand]

As you can see, I just drew the green and yellow functions by hand, these are the functions I'm interested in.
As far as I can tell there are a few constraints that define these two functions. Since those constraints are very similar, I'll only provide them for the green function, which I will call $f(x)$:

1. $f(x)$ has to be strictly convex ($f''(x)>0$)
2. $f(x) \geq S(x)\,\forall x > 0$
3. $f(x)=S(x)\Rightarrow f'(x)=S'(x)$
4. $\int_0^\infty f(x)-S(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ should be minimized

These 4 constraints (and their counterparts for the yellow function) should in theory define the functions I'm searching well. However, I haven't yet found a method to actually determine these functions.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: From the asymptotics for large $x$ given in the Wikipedia, you can certainly infer that these curves are asymptotic to $$
\sqrt {\frac{\pi }{8}}  \pm \frac{1}{{2x}}
$$ for large positive $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Although of arguable simplicity, there are two such functions, detailed further in *An Atlas of Functions* (Chapter 39: The Fresnel Integrals).

Associated with the Fresnel integrals are the auxiliary Fresnel cosine and sine integrals (sometimes designated $f$ and $g$), which the book calls *Fres* and *Gres* respectively.

These functions can be defined in several ways, the simplest probably being as follows:
$$
F(x)=(\frac{1}{2}-S(x))\cos(x^2)-(\frac{1}{2}-C(x))\sin(x^2)\\
G(x)=(\frac{1}{2}-S(x))\sin(x^2)+(\frac{1}{2}-C(x))\cos(x^2)
$$
where $S(x)$ and $C(x)$ are the sine and cosine Fresnel integrals.

When graphed, the auxiliary functions look like this:
[image: Graph of Fresnel and auxiliary Fresnel integrals]
(Image from book)

The upper bounds of the Fresnel integrals is $\frac{1}{2}+F(x)+G(x)$, and the lower $\frac{1}{2}-F(x)-G(x)$. These are only valid when $x\gt0$ (though in practice, this range actually extends a small amount back).

I've created an interactive graph of these functions [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n8ir8ceadh). Note the definitions of the Fresnel integrals; the $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ scaling factor *is* necessary for the above auxiliary definitions to work.

As to your requirements:

1. Since the bounds functions extend into negative values of $x$, where they oscillate, the functions as a whole are clearly not either purely concave or convex. On the domain $(0, \infty)$ however, I think they are.
   The above definitions of the Fresnel integrals converge to $\frac{1}{2}$. In the auxiliary functions, these are subtracted from $\frac{1}{2}$ to converge to $0$ overall.
   Each auxiliary is composed of two opposing 'blocks' ($(\frac{1}{2}-S(x))\cos(x^2)$ and $(\frac{1}{2}-C(x))\sin(x^2)$ in $F(x)$) that cancel out each other's oscillations. As the oscillations present in the Fresnel integrals decrease in amplitude as $x$ approaches $\infty$, you are left with essentially the difference between the 'center' of each Fresnel integral and $\frac{1}{2}$, which will always (I think) decrease towards $0$, at least in $G(x)$. $F(x)$ actually becomes briefly concave near $0$, but this issue seems to vanish when combined with $G(x)$.
   You could calculate the second derivative yourself to try and prove this if you wanted.
2. I cannot provide a proof for this either, but as per the book, the Fresnel integrals exist purely in the envelope created by the two above bounds functions.
3. As far as I know, the bounds functions never actually touch either of the Fresnel integrals, though (as usual) I cannot prove this. I do not know of any other bounds functions which do.
   That being said, since the derivative of either of the Fresnel integrals decreases after a maxima, necessarily to a greater degree than the upper bounds (as it oscillates), there should always be a point on either of the bounds functions (applying the same logic to the lower bound) *near* an extrema point which satisfies this requirement.
4. I'm not sure if the above functions satisfy this, sorry. I'd guess probably not, as a theoretically perfect function would essentially trace a straight line between the maxima (or as close as possible, rather).
   With some slight curvature at the tangent points to keep requirement 3, and some infinitely small curvature on the 'straight' sections to keep 1, there probably exists some 'better' function, though I have no idea what that might be.

Apologies for not being able to rigorously answer any of your questions, or even show how you obtain these functions, but hopefully this is of some use to you.

*Oldham, Keith B.; Myland, Jan; Spanier, Jerome*, An atlas of functions. With Equator, the atlas function calculator. With CD-ROM, New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 978-0-387-48806-6/hbk). xi, 748 p. (2008). [ZBL1167.65001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1167.65001).

Comment: Calculating the second derivatives, $G(x)$ will violate requirement 1 if $F(x)=2x^2G(x)$ for some $x>0$. I will update this answer with the derivation of that equation, and the results, if I can solve this. Wolfram claims that it does, for an extremely high value, though I am suspicious that this is just the result of inaccuracy.

Comment: Actually, that's incorrect; the requirement was for the bounds function, not $G(x)$ (of course), my bad. The actual equation is a little more complicated.

Comment: For moderate or large values of $x$, one can obtain accurate upper and lower bounds from the asymptotic expansions with error bounds: $$
F(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }x}\left( \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} (-1)^n \frac{(4n)!}{(2n)!}\frac{1}{(4x)^{2n} }  + ( - 1)^N \frac{(4N)!}{(2N)!}\frac{1}{(4x)^{2N} }\theta _{1,N} (x) \right)$$ and $$
G(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi }x}\left( \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N-1} (-1)^n \frac{(4n+2)!}{(2n+ 1)!}\frac{1}{(4x)^{2n+1}}+(-1)^N \frac{(4N+2)!}{(2N+1)!}\frac{1}{(4x)^{2N+1} }\theta _{2,N}(x)  \right)
$$ with $0<\theta_{1,N}(x),\theta_{2,N}(x)<1$ for any $N\ge 0$ and $x>0$.